# How to get the value of variable a from below code?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

```
request(target, function (err, resp, body) {
    $ = cheerio.load(body);
    links = $('a'); 
    $(links).each(function (i, link) {
        if ($(link).text().match('worker')) {
            var a = $(link).attr('href').toString();
        }
    });
});
```

I want to use the output of variable `a` in further program. Any pointers?

Comment: declare a as a global variable, on top `var a;` then you can be able to use it at other places

Comment: declaring a at top giving me weird result 'undefined' . Any thing else?

Comment: Will the link only match once? `if($(link).text().match('worker'))`

Comment: writing an answer for you right now, give me a bit :P

Comment: The usual approach would be to add a callback, which is then called with `a` as its argument.

Comment: @Arg0n it can match n number of times

Answer (score 2):

You have two alternative ways to give the variable `a` a global scope:

1. Declare it outside the `request` function (*) and just assign it inside the `each` cycle (**), *i.e.*:

   ```
   var a; // (*)
   request(target, function (err, resp, body) {
       $ = cheerio.load(body);
       links = $('a'); 
       $(links).each(function (i, link) {
           if ($(link).text().match('worker')) {
               a = $(link).attr('href').toString(); // (**)
           }
       });
   });
   ```
2. Simply remove the variable declaration inside the `each` cycle (*), *i.e.*:

   ```
   request(target, function (err, resp, body) {
       $ = cheerio.load(body);
       links = $('a'); 
       $(links).each(function (i, link) {
           if ($(link).text().match('worker')) {
               a = $(link).attr('href').toString(); // (*)
           }
       });
   });
   ```

   (If you assign a value to a variable that has not been declared, it will automatically become a global variable).

Comment: now if I m printing a i.e. console.log(a) Output is udefined

Comment: @user561810 that's because `request` is an asynchronous function!

Comment: @user561810 we're going off-topic; maybe you should study how asynchronous functions work, then ask a new question about them.

Comment: my question was "I want to use the value of variable a in furtther program", which is not happening with the solution you have given. So 1.) what is the advantage of making it global varaible, when i cannot use it further ?

Comment: @user561810 You can use the global variable further. The question is not so much "how?", but "when?".

Answer (score 0):

the `var` declaration is `function`-scoped. This means it can only be used within the function it's declared in.

Explanation:

```
// 'a' does not exist
$(links).each(function (i, link) {
    if($(link).text().match('worker')){
        var a=$(link).attr('href').toString();
        // 'a' exists'
    }
    // 'a' exists'
});
// 'a' does not exist
```

There are certain 'hacks' out there, like not 'declaring' it with `var`, `let` or `const`. Doing it like that automatically makes it '[global](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)', but this ofcourse has it drawbacks regarding memory usage and potential memory leaks (the same can be achieved with putting `var` outside of the functions).

A better way to use it might be to split the functionality up a bit more and just let one function call another (or with callbacks, but I hate callbacks and they're not the solution to everything).

Comment: can't we do it--> ? var a =function()/*blah bah*/ in NOdeJS? . just like in scala

Comment: ofcourse you can declare `var a = function() {}`, but then second you go `a = $(link).attr('href').toString();`, `a` is no longer that function.
I'm getting the idea it might come in handy to first learn more about JavaScript, before continuing with Node.js

Comment: so in other words, that thing is not possible in NodeJS

Comment: Well, first of all: It's JavaScript. Node.js is only a server side framework that runs JavaScript.
Second: ofcourse it's possible, but like @Alessio Cantarella and I said, you might want to start to learn more about JavaScript and the Asynchronous part about JavaScript, before continuing this project.

Answer (score 0):

If you do like this:

JavaScript

```
var savedLinks;
request(target, function (err, resp, body) {
    savedLinks = [];
    $ = cheerio.load(body);
    links = $('a'); 
    $(links).each(function (i, link) {
        if ($(link).text().match('worker')) {
            var a = $(link).attr('href').toString();
            savedLinks.push(a);
        }
    });
});
```

Then you can iterate through `savedLinks`.

Like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < savedLinks.length; i++) {
   console.log(savedLinks[i]);
}
```

You have to call the function `request` at some point for it to be initialized though of course.

Comment: for(var i=0;i<savedLinks.length;i++){
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined